# How can I see what file was sent to my website via POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have an IIS 7 server and a website that accepts XML POSTs. When I design it in my test environment I can set a break point and walk thru and see what is POSTed. 
But when I upload the code to the server and someone posts an XML they get no response and I cannot see anything on my end to debug why.

What I would like is to see the contents of his POST.
Should I se my website to write a log file or is there somewhere in IIS7 I should be looking?

I am using .Net and not PHP.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader ( Page.Request.InputStream );
        String xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        System.IO.StreamWriter SW;
        SW = File.CreateText ( Server.MapPath(".")+@"\"+ Guid.NewGuid () + ".xml" );
        SW.WriteLine ( xmlData );
        SW.Close ();
    }
```

Comment: I was looking for a way in IIS for logging type stuff, but I suspected this might be the path I would have to take.
Thanks for taking the time to answer, much appreciated.